# Multi-Gateway OpenVPN Setup

Tags: openvpn

Is it possible to setup multi-gateway OpenVPN servers e.g. Completely distinct virtual networks, lans and PKI.

Example: 
Site 1 acts as Gateway 1. Client A can connect as openvpn client to Gateway 1.

Site 2 acts as Gateway 2. Client Z can connect as openvpn client to Gateway 2.

Client A should not be able to connect GW 2. Client Z should not be able to connect to C

Client A should be able to route to a resource on the Lan behind GW 2.
Client Z should not be able to route to a resource behind GW 1.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

You should have two separate IP subnets on the VPN server, that is, either VLANs or physical Ethernet adapters. You configure each network adapter (physical or virtual) to a separate bridge. For each bridge, you include a separate `tap` interface.

Then, you have two OpenVPN configuration files. Each one of those uses a separate port for the incoming connection, separate `tap` interface for VPN traffic, separate PKI and separate default gateways which are sent to VPN clients. You can also allow clients to use DHCP for address allocation and default gateway setup, then you don't need to setup default gateway in OpenVPN configuration.

In client configuration, you use different ports and keys depending on which gateway you want to use.